# How to pass props to child component after the parent finshed the ajax call?

Tags: vue.js

I have a parent component that once `mounted()` makes and ajax call updates some of it's DOM and passes some data to one of it's child components, all the data from the ajax response.

The child also has a ajax call on `mounted()` and it sends along the prop it receives from the parent,

The problem is that that the child component fires the ajax call before the parent, how can mount the child after the parent gets the data from ajax ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `v-if` in the parent to delay the rendering of the child until the data is ready:

*Parent*

```html
<child v-if="parentData" :prop="parentData"></child>
```

```js
data() {
  return {
    parentData: null
  }
},
async mounted() {
  const response = await axios.get(...);
  this.parentData = response.data;
}
```

Comment: That stops the child from showing, but the ajax in the child still fires ..

Comment: The child's mounted hook can only run once the component is initialized, which can't happen until the `v-if` is `true`.  If the child's mounted hook fires, it's because the `parentData` has finished loading, that's the idea.

Comment: @Radu so why do you decide to use the `mounted` function of some child, when you need to have all the data first? That means you'd like to delay the mounted function. Cant you just have the child component watch a property?

Comment: @Flame The `v-if` is essentially a `watch` in the parent template.  There's no need to manually watch the prop in the child, though that is an alternative

Comment: @Dan yes but v-if prevents rendering/mounting as you said (im not sure if its retriggerable?). I cant tell if OP wants to have it rendered

Comment: @Flame Whenever the data comes in, that's when the child will be rendered, `mounted`, etc.  This way guarantees the prop is ready first but yeah, maybe OP wants something else to happen

Comment: @Dan That works but it still gives an error - parentData is undefined and then it works, I don't think that's normal

Comment: This won't throw any error.  It's expected that `parentData` will be `null` until the data is loaded.  As long as it's not being used anywhere, that's no problem. This is why it's best to show your code so we can see any mistakes that are being made.